# Java regex to remove leading and 'in word' asterisks

Tags: java, regex, asterisk

I'm looking for a regex to remove all trailing asterisks and all asterisks inside a word.

```
*He*llo* -> Hello* <br>
Thi*s *is* *a* t*est* -> This is* a* test*
```

Ending asterisks should be accepted.

I'm not really experienced with regexes. I know I can write a simple program that loops through each word of a string and remove trailing and 'in-word' asterisks -
but I wonder whether my problem can be solved using a regex, or not.

Hope that you can help me.
Thank you in advance.

Best regards,
Ioannis K.

Comment: Just a note, 2nd result should be "This is* a* test*", right?

Comment: Yes, Betlista. I just wanted to have at maximum one asterisk at the end. Found my solution. Thank you once again to all helper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use look ahead.

Take a look here : 
http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

This is something like : \*(?!( |$))

This regex says : delete all * which are not followed by a space or the end of the line.
(not tested)

Comment: Unfortunately neither of the provided regexes work.
I tested a bit arround - but had no success.

The in-word asterisks disappear.
But multiple trailing or leading asterisks remain.

Oh I see.. I wanted to say "leading asterisks should be removed and in-word", sorry!!

`***He*ll*o** -> Hello*` . I just want at maximum one asterisk at the end.

Sorry, that was my mistake!

Comment: what about look ahead ? What's the result of it ?

Comment: There was a '\' missing at the beginning. So I was not able to convert it.
This works very fine now!

Thank you so much!

`string.replaceAll("\\*(?!( |$))", "");`

Comment: great ! I wasn't understand why a look ahead can cause some asterisks to remain ;)

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
\**\b
```

with the empty string, globally.

Java uses strings to represent regular expressions, so you have to escape accordingly:

```
"\\**\\b"
```

Comment: The problem is:

`***T*h*i*s** **is *a* **t*est* -> **This** *is a* *test*`

It should be: `This* is a* test*`.
Sorry for my mistake. Did not specify my problem enough!

Answer (score 1):

```java
    final String[] in = { "*He*llo*", "Thi*s is *a* t*est*" };
    for ( final String s : in ) {
        System.out.println( s.replaceAll( "\\*(\\b)", "$1" ) );
    }
```

Comment: beware that \\b can cause problems. it will not work with special characters (but the question is quite obscure about it)

Comment: Thank you, but that does not work as expected.

`***T*h*i*s** is *a* t*est* -> **This** is a* test*`

There are still trailing asterisks.
And at the end there are also multiple asterisks.

Comment: @Tomalak I missed the idea of your updated solution "Replace `\**\b` with the empty string, globally." - substring `" "` of `String` `"A B"` is matching this pattern so you modify `"A B" -> "AB"` ?